# React UI not re-rendering on click even though DB is updated correctly. After second click, UI re-renders

Tags: reactjs, state, json-server

I'm calling a completeTask function within a todo list

```
    </IconButton>
    {task.isComplete ? (
      <Button
        startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
        onClick={() => completeTask(task.id)}
      >
        Mark as not complete
      </Button>
    ) : (
      <Button
        startIcon={<CheckIcon />}
        onClick={() => completeTask(task.id)}
      >
        Complete Task
      </Button>
    )}
```

However, when I click complete, the json server db updates but the UI doesn't update, until the second click

const completeTask = async (id) => {

```
const taskToToggle = await fetchTask(id)
const updTask = {...taskToToggle, isComplete: !taskToToggle.isComplete}

const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/tasks/${id}`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(updTask)
})

const data = await res.json()

setTasks(
  tasks.map((task) =>
    task.id===id ? {...task, isComplete:!data.isComplete} :task
  )
)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I ensure the UI re-renders after each click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is the new value, you don't need use `!data.isComplete`. Just update without `!`

```
setTasks(
  tasks.map((task) =>
    task.id===id ? {...task, isComplete:data.isComplete} :task
  )
)
```

Comment: In my case, I need to switch it to the opposite value because I'm using the same button to undo the completion of the task. Is there a way I can incorporate this?

Comment: Sorry-  that was the answer!! Thank you!